# How to enforce synchronous execution of separate Jenkins jobs?

Tags: jenkins

Our Jenkins server is configured with two primary jobs to build apks.  Each of those jobs has a child job that installs the APK onto an Android device that is attached to the build server and executes UI tests.

For example:

> Project-A-apk
>   Project-A-tests
>   Project-B-apk
>   Project-B-tests

where

> Project-A-apk kicks off Project-A-tests
>   Project-B-apk kicks off Project-B-tests

and

> both Project-A-tests and Project-B-tests install and run on the same test device.

The issue is, we can't have the test jobs running at the same time, as they will both try to interact with the same device.

Is there a way to configure a job to wait until some other job (not in it's parent chain) before executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the [Jenkins Exclusion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin) to manage our builds that have to share a couple of different DB resources. This plug works by allowing you to define Critical Blocks in your build steps.  Critical blocks will only run if they can acquire a specific resource.  At the end of the block the resource is released. This means that you don't have to block an entire job, just the parts that you need the resource for.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) to control when jobs should run concurrently.

Setup a category name such as android-device with Maximum Concurrent Builds Per Node set to 1. Assign this category to the jobs that run the test on the android device. Once the plugin is installed there is a place to assign the category on the job configuration page.

All jobs with the same category name assigned will execute serially instead of concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin):

> This plugin keeps the actual job in the queue if at least one name of
>   currently running jobs is matching with one of the given regular
>   expressions.

Another way would be to limit the number of Jenkins executors to one. This would ensure that only one job is running and other wait in queue. However, this might block other future jobs that do not access the test device.

Answer (score 0):

One more: [Heavy Job Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin)

You can weight your Android jobs to block all executors.